# A Blocking Concurrent Collection - Take method that takes an item that supports a condition

Tags: c#, thread-safety, concurrent-collections

I would like to have a concurrent collection which supports a **blocking** thread-safe `Take` operation, while the actual item taken is an item that satisfies a condition.

Something like:

```
private TheBlockingCollection<MyClass> _myCollection;

MyClass myItem = _myCollection.TakeItemWhere(item => item.Type.equals(something));
```

The final goal would be to take the item with the highest property value that currently exists in the collection. e.g. - Max

Is there such a built in collection?

If not, what would be the better alternative?

Comment: Would you expect it to go through all available items, taking whichever one matches the predicate first? Or block until the first item matches the predicate?

Comment: I *very* much doubt that you'll find anything built into the existing collections which will meet that requirement. It sounds like you possibly want to have *multiple* collections (one per type) and order each of those by priority.

Comment: I would have done that. But in my case the property is an int, that represents priority. so separation to multiple collection according to the value is not possible...

Comment: It sounds like you don't actually need this; it sounds like you could just have the underlying collection be a priority queue that provides the item with the highest priority without needing to specify a condition when taking an item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Servy mentions in a comment above, you should use a Priority Queue with a BlockingCollection.

If you implement an appropriate `IComparable<>` interface for the types being stored in the collection, then when you dequeue items you will automatically get the item that is first according to the comparison interface you defined.

[Microsoft have provided a sample `ConcurrentPriorityQueue`](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Samples-for-Parallel-b4b76364/sourcecode?fileId=44488&pathId=1696822056) which implements `IProducerConsumerCollection` that you can use with a BlockingCollection.

You use it by first creating an instance of a `ConcurrentPriorityQueue` and then by creating the BlockingCollection using one of the constructors which accepts a `IProducerConsumerCollection<T>`, for example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287133.aspx

You just need to pass the `ConcurrentPriortyQueue` to that constructor.

Comment: Sounds great, I will check it out as soon as I can